# MySQL join 2 tables with different columns

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables i.e. contacts and users.

I have this query:

```
 SELECT contacts.id AS 'contacts_id', contacts.assigned_user_id AS 'Assigned_to0' FROM  contacts  WHERE contacts.date_entered < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL + 15 day) AND contacts.deleted = 0 limit 1;
+--------------------------------------+---------------+
| contacts_id                          | Assigned_to0  |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+
| cdb8dae0-eb8b-bd1e-5667-53984aa7a5dd | seed_sally_id |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+
```

I have the first_name, last_name from users

```
select id,first_name,last_name from users where id='seed_sally_id';
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| id            | first_name | last_name |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| seed_sally_id | Sally      | Bronsen   |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
```

So, in the result of **Assigned_to0** I require the first_name + last_name instead of id(seed_sally_id) for the first query.
I'm presuming a (LEFT)JOIN statement is required here?

Thanks in advance.

John

Comment: what have you tried ? because this looks like you have tried some before... or is there a reason why you use the tablename before column namen if you only select one table ? is contacts id the same id as user id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT contacts.id AS 'contacts_id',
       concat(users.first_name,' ' ,users.last_name) as Assigned_to0
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN users ON contacts.assigned_user_id=users.id
WHERE contacts.date_entered < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL + 15 DAY)
  AND contacts.deleted = 0
  AND users.id='seed_sally_id';
```

Comment: concat with INNER JOIN, that's what I was looking for.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

This statement do the job

```
SELECT contacts.id AS 'contacts_id', contacts.assigned_user_id AS 'Assigned_to0' , users.first_name, users.last_name
FROM  contacts  join users on contacts.Assigned_to0  =users.id
WHERE contacts.date_entered < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL + 15 day) AND contacts.deleted = 0 limit 1;
```

Comment: Remove space between `contacts` and `.Assigned_to0` at ON clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id AS 'contacts_id', c.assigned_user_id AS 'Assigned_to0',
       u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM contacts c, users u
WHERE c.deleted = 0
  AND c.assigned_user_id=u.id
  AND c.date_entered < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL + 15 DAY)
  AND u.id='seed_sally_id' limit 1;
```

untested